# No C wire connection on old Goodman furnace

Tags: furnace, thermostat-c-wire

I have read for hours, and tried figure this out myself, but I need help. I'm trying to connect the Blue C wire from the tstat, without a C terminal at the furnace.

[image]From what I have read, it seems to me that I would connect the C wire from the thermostat, to one of the 3 BL wires coming from the 24v transformer. If that is correct, I am still not sure which of the 3 BL wires to use.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: All 3 are connected to the same point on the transformer. It shouldn't matter which one you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'll connect to *any* of the blue wires coming from the transformer.

If there's an empty terminal on the transformer, connect there. If not, you might be able to use a piggyback spade connector.

[image]

Otherwise, connecting at the point of grounding would be the next easiest location.

[image]